# Can not replace string in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a template is loaded by **email_template** table. I try to replace some elements in this template by Postgres REPLACE. Something like this

Note: *content* column: varchar

```
UPDATE email_template SET content = replace (content,
                '
                    <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/" alt="Facebook"/></a></td>
                    <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/" alt="Facebook 1"/></a></td>
                    <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/" alt="Facebook 2"/></a></td>
                    <td><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/" alt="Facebook 3"/></a></td>
                ',
                '   <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/" alt="Youtube"/></a></td>
                    <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/" alt="Youtube 1"/></a></td>
                    <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/" alt="Youtube 2"/></a></td>
                    <td><a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/" alt="Youtube 3"/></a></td>
                ') WHERE template_id=1;
```

The issue is the template in *content* rows is too long. The sql query is not wrong but it is not updated in the email_template table. Still stored the old value :(

Does anyone have the solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: content is defined as a varchar of what length?

Comment: @Andrew: Hi, it's varchar(4000)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see,  simply updating `facebook` to `youtube` should work for you, right?

```
UPDATE email_template
   SET content =
          REGEXP_REPLACE (content,
                          'facebook',
                          'Youtube',
                          'gi') WHERE template_id=1;
```

Comment: Hi,
The query above is just a sample for my requirement. I still can't change the element in template :(

I have e template which put in CONTENT column => want to change some elements in this template => but the template contains too many lines => Query did not updated :(

Comment: @Quinn Tran : First list down all the patterns from the source string you would need to be replaced in the target. Then construct a regexp pattern, rather than replacing whole lengthy blocks like you r doing..